# Maven plugin dependencies purpose

Tags: maven, plugins, build

If I want to download and use a maven plugin, is it necessary to have all the dependencies of the plugin too? Or are they only required to build the plugin?

Comment: You need the dependencies of the plugin itself, cause the code inside the plugin uses such dependencies. But it depends. Can you be a little bit more accurate what exactly you like to achieve?

Comment: I want to include the maven-dependency-plugin in a zip to be used to provision a separate machine. so do i need just the jar or all of its dependencies as well if it's just the executable jar that i need?